# Class 'GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I'm trying to run LaunchDarkly and within the code it says that I need to initialize my class like so

```
$client = new LDClient("MY_CLIENT_KEY");
```

Now I was able to do that but an error occured below is the error

[image]

The error is within this code $stack = HandlerStack::create(); inisde the GuzzleFeatureRequester.php. Its trying to call

```
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
```

but this class does not exist when searching. Any idea on how to fix this?
I'm using this on my composer.json

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3.0",
"launchdarkly/launchdarkly-php": "^2.0"
```

Comment: That's an old version of Guzzle. Consider giving `6.2.2` a try?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy maybe this is not an option as the system is already using this old version and a lot of changes has been made on guzzle 6. If we switch to the latest version a lot of module will break

Comment: If it's help to anyone down the line: my issue was trying to use the `Http` Laravel request helper without having installed guzzle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at the dependency of the **launchdarkly-php**?

It uses guzzlehttp v6.

**Want the proof it's over here:**

Just have a look at the `composer.json` over here:

https://github.com/launchdarkly/php-client/blob/master/composer.json#L22

> "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2.1",

And since you are working on guzzle v5 there is no any class that you have specified.

So, **if you are trying to work on `launchdarkly v2 sdk` try to upgrade to guzzlehttp v6.**

Else as you mentioned that there is **more dependency with guzzlehttp v5 then you need to use:**

```
"launchdarkly/launchdarkly-php": "0.7.0"
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Great then I have no other choice then.. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

your laravel version should be compatible with guzzle versions

Laravel 5.8: Guzzle ^6.0 (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.8.38/composer.json#L124)
Laravel 6: Guzzle ^6.3.1|^7.0.1(https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.20.2/composer.json#L126)
Laravel 7: Guzzle ^6.3.1|^7.0.1 (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v7.29.2/composer.json#L132)
Laravel 8: Guzzle ^6.5.5|^7.0.1 (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v8.12.3/composer.json#L135)